# Workaround to timeupdate event not firing on the video element in iOS or Android

Tags: android, ios, events, html5-video

I'm finding that the timeupdate event does not fire on either Safari iOS or Android (2.2, if not others).  I've tried removing the controls attribute, as others have suggested that they absorb all  events, but with no luck.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you were going to do with the event.

If you're simply looking to find out the current time, maybe set a timer to query for it when 'playing' is fired and remove it on 'paused'. Maybe also query on 'seeked'.